# How to speed up mahotas haralick feature calculation for larger distances

Tags: python, glcm, mahotas

I'm using https://github.com/luispedro/mahotas for calculation of GLCM values. My images are of different dimensions and I'm using the argument distance depending on the size of the images. When I increase the distance to greater than 100 or 200 pixels then the calculation takes too long and there is a big spike in RAM usage. Is there a way to speed it up.